# File is not getting deleted in Android 13?

Tags: java, android, delete-file

```
String path = "/storage/emulated/0/Recordings/Call/Two.mp3";
File file = new File(path);

if(file.exists()) {
File file2 = new File(file.getAbsolutePath());
    file2.delete();
    Toast.makeText(this, "File deleted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    finish();   
}else 
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "File not exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();        
}
```

File is not getting deleted. But the toast is showing as File Deleted.I trapped on this issue almost 2 days, any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I used the below permission in the manifest.

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

[image]

Comment: You do not have write access to arbitrary files on Android 11+. That will include the ability to delete arbitrary files.

Comment: Do I remove the permission  from manifest ?

Comment: If you want to be able to delete that file on Android 10 and below, you would need `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` (including requesting it at runtime).

Comment: So, Do I delete the permission for android 10+ devices ?

Comment: You could if you wanted. That is your decision.

Comment: Even now file is not deleting

Comment: Well, sure. As I wrote earlier, you do not have write access to arbitrary files on Android 11+. That will include the ability to delete arbitrary files.

Comment: Ok Thanks @CommonsWare, But Whats the solution for my current issue

Comment: AFAIK, there is none. You cannot just randomly delete whatever you want anymore. If you are willing to involve the user, it might be possible to delete something that the user chooses via `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` / `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument`, though I have not tried this. You could ask that the user grant you `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, but then you may not be allowed to distribute your app on the Play Store or elsewhere. Personally, I would simply not delete files in arbitrary locations.

Comment: I used the above permissions and  I already published app in the playstore

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250891/discussion-between-anandh-krishnan-and-commonsware).

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution # 1

For Android 11 or higher, you can delete file using [MediaStore Api](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore#createDeleteRequest(android.content.ContentResolver,%20java.util.Collection%3Candroid.net.Uri%3E)) (without `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_Storage`)

In `onCreate()`

```
String path = "/storage/emulated/0/Recordings/Call/Two.mp3";

private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> deleteResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), result -> {
        if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getApplicationContext(), new String[]{path}, null, (path, uri) -> {
                Log.d("onScanCompleted", uri.getPath());
            });
        }
    });
```

you delete function,

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));

        ArrayList<Uri> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayList.add(fileUri);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = MediaStore.createDeleteRequest(getContentResolver(), arrayList);
        deleteResultLauncher.launch(new IntentSenderRequest.Builder(pendingIntent).build().getFillInIntent());
    }
```

#### Solution 2

With `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_Storage`, just add `MediaScannerConnection`

```
String path = "/storage/emulated/0/Recordings/Call/Two.mp3";
File file = new File(path);

if (file.exists()) {
    File file2 = new File(file.toString());
    file2.delete();
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getApplicationContext(), new String[]{path}, null, (path, uri) -> {
            Log.d("onScanCompleted", uri.getPath());
        });
    Toast.makeText(this, "File deleted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    finish();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "File not exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Hi @Sohaib, I used your solution 2. But its not working,

Comment: even now File deleted toast is showing but the file is not getting deleted bro

Comment: Can you give a try for 1st solution?

Comment: I have updated my answer, plz update this line `File file2 = new File(file.toString());`

Comment: Ok bro I will check

Comment: actually its not issue bro

Comment: the issue is its not working on android 11+ devices

Comment: I cant use this registerForActivityResult bro. Because Im working on broadcastReceiver

Comment: Yes, I get that, I'm actually using this code and it worked for me

Comment: are you using in broadcast receiver ?

Comment: No, in fragments

Comment: @Sohaid Ahmad , Thanks for your help. I can not use this in fragment or actiivty, Because I need this function on my Broadcast reciever class(ex. I need to call this while incoming call receiving)