# Delete file in Android 13

Tags: java, android

I create a png file in the "/Pictures/test/test.png" folder and sometimes I delete it and create a new file and it works fine.

But when I delete the app and reinstall it, I can no longer delete the file

If I delete the png file by myself once, the app will work again

I think the app can only delete the files it created and sometimes when I reinstall the app, Android recognizes the app as a stranger.

```
file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),FolderName);
    if (!file.exists()){
        file.mkdirs();
        if (file.isDirectory()){
           Toast.makeText(this, "Folder created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
          Toast.makeText(this, "Folder creation failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}}
    if (file.exists()){
        File out_c_file= new File(file,FileName);
        if(out_c_file.exists()){out_c_file.delete();}
```

This problem does not exist in Android 6

Comment: Indeed. After reinstall the file does not belong to the app anymore hence can not be deleted in the classic way. But you can use SAF to let the user choose the file. ACTION_,OPEN_DOCUMENT.

Comment: In Android 13 you need the Permission-Dialog for deleting Images. The dialog is automatically shown when using the ContentResolver afaik

Comment: It makes no sense to use mkdirs() if you want to delete a file.

Comment: Check out this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/75033288/8063735

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the code like this, I will check if the file is not deleted, I will use a random name and save this name in the app, and I will use this name many times later.